# Is "follow in" the correct phrasal verb to use in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

> They stepped into the house and issues followed in. (**ISSUES BEGAN**)

Is the use of ***followed in*** correct in this context? If not, how can I rewrite it with a better phrase?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in other words what it is you want to say? Then we could explore the best way to say it. At the moment your sentence doesn't sound great; at the very least you need a pronoun "... issues followed *them* in". Even then, it doesn't sound very natural.

Comment: Why would you *want* to say that the issues "followed [them] in"? I can't see any useful *meaning* conveyed here by the "quasi-metaphoric" reference to ***topics*** travelling "behind" the people who discuss them.

Comment: Did you mean to write _followed on_?

Comment: @JMB edited the question

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I don't know. It just appeared in my mind while writing that sentence. Wanted to know whether it's correct. May I please know what is meant by "quasi-metaphoric"?

Comment: @Clicker "Follow in" doesn't work. "Begin" is a valid option, as you suggest. How about something like "They stepped into the house and that was when the issues began"? If you want to focus on the moment, you could try something like "No sooner had they stepped into the house than the issues began".

Comment: @JMB Your second suggestion serves the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Prefix ***quasi-*** means ***seemingly, but not really**.* I'm saying that to talk about abstract things like topics / issues ***following*** people around and/or ***appearing later** [than the people they're associated with]* is "somewhat metaphorical" (abstract notions can't really move around in space like that).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an answer after some back and forth in the comments above.

"Follow in" doesn't work here. At the very least it would require a pronoun:

> issues followed **them** in

However, it's not natural to talk about problems following a person/people.

A better option would be to use the verb 'begin' or 'start':

> They stepped into the house and that was when the issues began

We could improve on this sentence by focussing on the moment the problems began (ie 'when they stepped into the house':

> No sooner had they stepped into the house than the issues began

Answer (score 1):

I am not native but you could say :
*issues followed them(in)*
OR
*problems/trouble started*
OR
*problems began to mount/began to develop*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

I like:

> In they came--and problems with them.
>
> When they stepped into the house, the nightmare began.
>
> They stepped in; I stepped out.